# Facing mapping exceptions after upgrading AutoMapper from 7.0.0 to 9.0.0

Tags: xamarin.forms, automapper

I had created mappings by using CreateMap<>() for my project and the version of AutoMapper was 7.0.0. With version 7.0.0 my application on Android and iOS was working fine.
I have updated AutoMapper version to 9.0.0 and now it throws exceptions of missing mappings which were not present in my MapperProfile file earlier and were of no use at version 7.0.0.
Providing whole code is not possible here

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/9.0-Upgrade-Guide.html

Comment: I have already referred Upgrade Guide. But did not get the exact idea. Can you please state something?

Comment: If that doc doesn't help, I think it's a lot easier to not upgrade.